# Kubectl attach vs kubectl exec?

Tags: kubernetes

by using `kubectl exec -ti POD_NAME bash` I am able to access the terminal inside the container and execute the command.

I can understand the usability and convenient of the above command. As K8s Operator I use **exec** regularly.

However, What is the use case of `kubectl attach POD_NAME`?

How can it be **utilised**?
What is the real **purpose** of it?
In what situation or circumstance it can be used?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The use cases for kubectl attach are discussed in [kubernetes/issue 23335](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23335).

It can attach to the main process run by the container, which is not always bash.
As opposed to exec, which allows you to execute *any* process within the container (often: bash)

```
# Get output from running pod 123456-7890, using the first container by default
kubectl attach 123456-7890

# Get output from ruby-container from pod 123456-7890
kubectl attach 123456-7890 -c ruby-container
```

[This article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2015/10/some-things-you-didnt-know-about-kubectl_28#attach-to-existing-containers) proposes:

> In addition to interactive execution of commands, you can now also attach to any running process. Like `kubectl logs`, you’ll get stderr and stdout data, but **with attach, you’ll also be able to send stdin from your terminal to the program.
>
>   Awesome for interactive debugging, or even just sending <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to a misbehaving application.**

```
  $> kubectl attach redis -i
```

---

Again, the main difference is in the process you interact with in the container:

- exec: any one you want to create
- attach: the one currently running (no choice)

Answer (score 9):

*In Simplest words*

The `kubectl attach` command is similar to `kubectl exec`, but it attaches to the main process running in the `container` instead of running an additional one.